# two similar questions, one getting close votes?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed there are two very similar questions recently asked.  Both ask about how to engage in conversation when the OP is awkward or feels they don't have anything to converse about:

[How to talk to people at a singles mixer when you are an introvert?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/21104/6299) has gotten 3 close votes.

[How can a poor and socially handicapped person socialize with wealthy people?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/21096/6299) hasn't gotten any close votes.

I still tend to be baffled by what gets closed vs left open.  Any info on why one is getting closed and other isn't?  I'd particularly like to hear from people who saw both and voted to close one of them.

Comment: Maybe cause the first one isn't clearly stating a goal while the second is. But I neither was nor would VTC either of them.

Answer (score 2):

Community moderation isn't an instantaneous programmatic process. It's done by humans as a volunteer activity. People aren't omniscient. Posts need to be brought to their attention for any moderation activity to take place. More often than not that's the reason for differing amounts of activity on two similar posts.

Note how at the time of me writing this both posts are at 4 votes to close. I'm guessing that the act of making a post on meta got the second question added to the review queue, normalizing the number of votes between them.

Comment: ok, thanks.  I guess this is a case where I'm looking for a pattern that isn't there.